fullScreenCover doesn't respect the dynamic type changes?
I have view that I'd like to show as a fullScreenCover, I noticed one little issue after presenting it that it does not resize the font when the dynamic type changes. Is there a nice way of fixing this?

Here's my code
import SwiftUI

struct FullScreenModal: View {
    @State var showModal: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Parent view")
            Button("Open Modal") {
                showModal = true
            }
        }
        
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showModal, content: {
            Text("This is a full screen cover.")
        })
    }
}

#Preview {
    FullScreenModal()
}


Does this happen on a real device too? The previews have always been kind of glitchy.

@Sweeper Yes it does happen on the real device and also on the simulator as well... I think it's a bug on the fullScreenCover... See my answer, that's the easy way to solve it

I got inspired by @Martin Poulsen answer, so I want to keep the size categories the same on Parent and Child views, so for that you'd need to get an instance of sizeCategory Environment object and pass that on to the child the same way that Martin has done. Here's the working example:
import SwiftUI

struct FullScreenModal: View {
    @Environment(\.sizeCategory) var sizeCategory
    @State var showModal: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Parent view")
            Button("Open Modal") {
                showModal = true
            }
        }
        
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showModal, content: {
            Text("This is a full screen cover.")
                .environment(\.sizeCategory, sizeCategory)
        })
    }
}

#Preview {
    FullScreenModal()
}


